# VoiceOver in OS 10.10 adds default focus to button for QtQuick application

Tags: macos, qt, qml, voiceover

I have created an QtQuick application using Qt 5.6. I have added accessibility features in all the QML text and buttons. The accessibility features work correctly on Windows using JAWS 17.0 screen reader.
However, the same project if I run on Mac with OS 10.10, while using VoiceOver for screen reading, the focus remains on Button by default every time and Keyboard navigation doesn't work.

If I make changes in VoiceOver settings to follow focus on mouse movement, the focus changes properly.

Is there a way to change this behavior of VoiceOver for Qt project?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you make a short example that will reproduce the problem and post it here?

Comment: There is a default example for qtQuick called, qtquick accessibility. Can you please have a look into that or shall i paste that code here?

Comment: It is completely fine if there is an example. Thanks. I think it is worth mentioning it in the question.